# When is subquery factoring more performant than materialized view?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have seen this mentioned at 2-3 places that subquery factoring (Oracle With clause, also called as Common Table Expression) is more performant than materialized views in some cases, though no one mentions when.

Are there some cases when this is true and one should use Subquery Factoring on those occasions to get more performance.

Comment: Both are so different in terms of usage and implementation.  What is your business problem? Do you have any business case where you are stuck between opting the best among two? Or is it just a broad question?

Comment: Thanks Lalit. We have several queries that need to be optimized. I want to have a good understanding of the two to know which one to use where. So if you can give me some broad details on the differences between the two, I can ask some more specific questions too.

Comment: I realize my comment above may not be clear. The queries to be optimized need storing of intermediate results. Hence the need to distinguish between the two. At this point, we are inclining towards materialized views since they pre-compute the result on writes and hence lesser computation is required during reads. And this brings me to  the question - when are inline views more useful? Please suggest if I am not clear.

Comment: I would say, it is usually a bad idea to store computed values in database tables. You need to explain your business requirement. There is always a better approach than storing computed values.

Comment: I'd suggest that you ask when CTE's are more performant than MV's in the places where you heard it said

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle WITH clause is primarily a means to make your statements more readable. When the subquery appears *more than once* in your statement, Oracle ***may*** choose to evaluate the WITH clause only once and put its results into a temporary table. The undocumented hint MATERIALIZE is said to encourage Oracle to do so.

But anytime Oracle may also choose to inline the WITH clause in which case there would be no performance difference at all, compared to repeated subqueries. All in all my experiences with the performance benefits of WITH were somewhat disappointing.

Materialzed views in constrast do some work upfront and may improve performance no matter how many times they are referenced in a statement.